# How to place group of markers with transition effect?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, transition

I have to show vehicle movements in google map, so on click of of group i make ajax call it gets lat lng and some info of all vehicles then I place a marker on map. Here if vehicle moves for the next ajax call I get diff lat lng at that time I show transition effect to marker. this is giving me problem ,

Here is my callback function of Ajax,

```
function callBackFunction(http_request) {
  if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
    if (http_request.status == 200) {


        var rs = http_request.responseText;
       //here rs is as follow in servlet  fstring=fstring+lat+","+lng+"$"+vn+"@notsame@"+busImg+"@"+drvcdr+"#";
       var SlNo=0;
       var position="";
       var busImg="";
       clear_Icon();  
       while(rs.length)
       {
           lat=rs.substring(0,rs.indexOf(","));
           lng=rs.substring(rs.indexOf(",")+1,rs.indexOf("$"));
           vn=rs.substring(rs.indexOf("$")+1,rs.indexOf("@"));
           rs=rs.substring(rs.indexOf("@")+1);
           position=rs.substring(0,rs.indexOf("@"));
           rs=rs.substring(rs.indexOf("@")+1);

           busImg=rs.substring(0,rs.indexOf("@"));
           rs=rs.substring(rs.indexOf("@")+1);
           drvcdr=rs.substring(0,rs.indexOf("#")); 
           add_icon(lat,lng,SlNo,vn,position,busImg,drvcdr);

           rs=rs.substring(rs.indexOf("#")+1);
           SlNo++;
       }

    } else {
        alert('ERR OR: AJAX request status = ' + http_request.status);
    }
}
}
```

placing marker and transition effect,

```
function add_icon(lt, ln,n,vn,position,busImg,drvcdr)  {

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng( lt, ln);
        //alert("Icon: "+busImg);

        marker= createMarker(point,n,vn,position,busImg,drvcdr);
        alert("After Marker placed:"+point.lat()+"  "+point.lng());
        transitionnn(point);
      }

  var gmarkers = [];

  function createMarker(point, number,vn,position,busImg,drvcdr) {

            var angleDegrees = 150;
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  map: map,
                  raiseOnDrag: true,
                  icon:busImg,

                 // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  draggable: false,
                  zIndex: number,
                  id:vn,
                  drvcddr:drvcdr


              });             

      var html = number;

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'Latitude: ' + point.lat() +
          '<br>Longitude: ' + point.lng()  + '<br>BusNo : '+ marker.get("id")+ '<br>DrivrConductor : '+ marker.get("drvcddr"), 
          maxwidth: 1000
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });

      gmarkers.push(marker);
      return marker;
    };

    function transitionnn(point)
    {
      var result = [point.lat(), point.lng()];
      transition(result);
    }

    var numDeltas = 100;
    var delay = 100; //milliseconds
    var i = 0;
    var deltaLat;
    var deltaLng;


    function transition(result){

        i = 0;
        deltaLat = (result[0] - position[0])/numDeltas;
        deltaLng = (result[1] - position[1])/numDeltas;
        moveMarker();
    }

    function moveMarker(){
        position[0] += deltaLat;
        position[1] += deltaLng;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]);
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
        if(i!=numDeltas){
            i++;
            setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
        }
    }
```

The problem is , in map I get markers but not in exact position and transition effect also not showing currectly. I dont know where I am going wrong can anyone help me to solve this . THank you.

Comment: Looks like you are using custom icons, are those anchored correctly? What does "transition effect also not showing correctly" mean?

Comment: I haven't tested it, I'm just looking at the code; here are my first thoughts: I don't like the fact you put deltaLat & deltaLng as global.  These should be parameters of moveMarker() somehow.  ALso, the data you get from the server ought to be in JSON format, then you don't need that while with the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically the effect you want.

What I do: 4 cars start from Brussels; each time you click on the button, you get the next points.  Each marker transitions to its new spot.

The data should come from some DB (or so); I just use 3 sets of location (for each car)

Notice: you don't use jQuery.  So I made (kind of) a minimal version of $.ajax with raw javascript

ajax_json.php

```
<?php
$locations = json_decode(
  '[
    [{"lat": 50.8454638, "lng": 4.33719938}, {"lat": 50.8555429, "lng": 4.35711210}, {"lat": 50.8454638, "lng": 4.369300}, {"lat": 50.8331057, "lng": 4.35711210}],
    [{"lat": 51.0540382, "lng": 3.72185772}, {"lat": 51.2199126, "lng": 4.40142220}, {"lat": 50.96458043, "lng": 5.493295848}, {"lat": 50.45450295, "lng": 3.95242041}],
    [{"lat": 51.20249156, "lng": 3.22428649}, {"lat": 51.92036145, "lng": 4.4799894}, {"lat": 50.936165, "lng": 6.96152633}, {"lat": 49.258189, "lng": 4.03229659}]
]');

$t = isset($_GET['t']) ? (int) $_GET['t'] : 0;
echo json_encode(array('locations'=> $locations[$t], 'get'=> print_r($_GET, 1) ));
?>
```

index.php

```
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script>
  // a few globals
  var t = 0;
  var markers = [];  // let's keep this global, so we can easily access it everywhere
  var map;
  // settings (100 steps, each step is 20ms apart)
  var interval = 20;
  var steps = 100;

  // this function makes an Ajax call, to get the locations of the car.
  function getNextLocations() {
    ajax({
      success: receiveNextLocations,
      url: 'ajax_json.php?t=' + t,
      dataType: 'json'
    });
    t++;
  }
  // callback for the ajax call.  Gets triggerd when the next locations are received from the server
  function receiveNextLocations(data) {
    for (var i=0; i<data.locations.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i]) {
        // update marker position, we use transition
        markerTransition(markers[i], markers[i].getPosition(), new google.maps.LatLng(data.locations[i].lat, data.locations[i].lng), 0);
      }
      else {
        // new marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.locations[i].lat, data.locations[i].lng),
          map: map
        });
        // we store the markers in an array
        markers.push(marker);
      }
    }
  }
  // recursive function.  Takes a marker and moves it to a destination, in many steps
  function markerTransition(marker, oldPosition, newPosition, i) {
    // we calculate the temporary position
    var tempPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(
      oldPosition.lat() + i * (newPosition.lat() - oldPosition.lat()) / steps,
      oldPosition.lng() + i * (newPosition.lng() - oldPosition.lng()) / steps    
    );
    marker.setPosition(tempPosition);
    if(i<steps) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          markerTransition(marker, oldPosition, newPosition, i+1);
        },
        interval
      );
    }
  }

  // initialize Google Maps
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8, 4.7),
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script>
  // ajax function that looks a bit like jQuery $.ajax
  // minimal code for what I need; not dummy proof, no error handling ...
  // feel free to extend this
  var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  function ajax(options) {
    http_request.open(options.type || 'GET', options.url, true);
    http_request.send(options.data || null);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
          var type = options.dataType || '';
          switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
            default: 
              options.success(http_request.responseText);
              break;
            case 'json': 
              options.success(JSON.parse(http_request.responseText));
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<p id="map_canvas" ></p>
<input type="button" value="Next locations" onclick="getNextLocations()"><br><br>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: I am new to php , I just wana test your code so where do I have to place index.php? I use Eclipse , is this file to be placed in `webcontent` folder?

Comment: I haven't installed Eclipse in a while, I don't remember.  With Xampp you make a subfolder in the folder 'htdocs'.  Example: "C:\xampp\htdocs\maps\index.php" then becomes "http://localhost/maps/index.php"